# How to push a view outside the activity on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` which contains 2 views, a `LinearLayout` and a `RecyclerView`. This is how my `.XML` file looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        //A few image views
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to achieve, is to get the `LinearLayout` out of my activity when I scroll the `RecyclerView` and for that I'm using the following code:

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    private int scrollDistance = 0;
    private boolean isVisible = true;
    private static final float MINIMUM = 50;

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (isVisible && scrollDistance > MINIMUM) {
            linearLayout.animate().translationY(-linearLayout.getHeight() - 12); //Hide
            scrollDistance = 0;
            isVisible = false;
        } else if (!isVisible && scrollDistance < -MINIMUM) {
            linearLayout.animate().translationY(0); //Show
            scrollDistance = 0;
            isVisible = true;
        }

        if ((isVisible && dy > 0) || (!isVisible && dy < 0)) {
            scrollDistance += dy;
        }
    }
};
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
```

But I achieved to get out only the content of the `LinearLayout`. I also tried to add a listener to set the visibility of the `linearLayout` object to `GONE` when animation stops but the `RecyclerView` will fall into `LinearLayout` place's.

How can I get that `LinearLayout` smoothly out of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve.

1. Push the Linearlayout inside CollapsabletoolbarLayout
   https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example
2. Use viewtype property inside RecyclerAdapter and convert LinearLayout to HEADER of the recycler view.
   https://inducesmile.com/android/add-header-to-android-recyclerview/

You can find samples for the above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I achieve 1.?

Comment: But I'm not looking to use a `CollapsabletoolbarLayout`, I just want to get that `Linearlayout` out if the screen.

Comment: If you don't want that, you simple make it visibility gone

Comment: I did, but after the animation is finish, the `RecyclerView` fails in `LinearLayout` place's making this look bad. How can I solve this?